# How to pass value getting from Google sheets to Node JS to show into React Native as a Flatlist

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There is an async/await function which gets data from the Google sheets. I have used a return statement for a single cell value in the end of the function and when I pass this into node JS then it throws an error that argument must be of type string or array not a function. I am unable to pass the values from this function to React native app. Below is the sample code

```
    async function gsrun(cl){
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version : "v4", auth: cl});
    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId : '<spreadsheet id>',
        range: 'Range to get values'
    }
    var data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    var dataArray = data.data.values;            
    return dataArray[2][1]
    }
    var a = gsrun(client)
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send(a);
    })
```

Comment: `gsrun` is a `function` accepting 1 argument `cl`. You are not  calling the function. You are not calling the function with  argument `cl`

Comment: Now I passed that `cl` argument in the `gsrun` function but it returns empty `{ }` curly braces.

Comment: [Edit] to show latest code. async function returns a promise

Comment: What is the way out for this. I need to get this data and pass it to React native so that Flatlist can render this.

Comment: try `app.get("/", async function(req, res){
    res.send(await a);`

Comment: Thanks, it works. yesterday I was using Async/await function after `gsrun` and then passing the value to express node. Didn't think that express node function needs to be into async/await. One more think if you could help, I want to get the Name and quantity column from this dataArray [["id","Name ","Qty"],["1","Fateh","25"],["2","Fateh","100"],["3","Ambuja","140"],["4","Utcl","50"]]. what could be used to get it.

Comment: Better to ask a new question. For this  I'll add a answer to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues/Solution:

- You're passing a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) to `res.send`. You should call the function with `cl` first.
- [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) returns a promise. You need to `await` it's resolution

#### Snippet:

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res){ res.send(await gsrun(client));
```